# Second arugument of React.memo() not working properly in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to re render only when the minutes change using `React.memo()` like this:

```
function getCurrentTime(){
  let now = new Date();
  return ({
    'mins': now.getMinutes(),
    'secs': now.getSeconds()
  })
}


const Disp = React.memo(({ timeObj }) => { //this Component is suppose to be in another file
  return (<Text>{timeObj['mins']}</Text>);
}, (prevProp, newProp) => {

  if (prevProp['mins'] == newProp['mins'])
    return false;

  return true;
});


export default function App() {

  const [CurrentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(() => getCurrentTime());

  useEffect(() => {
    let secTimer = setInterval(() => {setCurrentTime(getCurrentTime())}, 500);
    return () => { clearInterval(secTimer) };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Disp timeObj={CurrentTime} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

but for some reason it isn't working & renders every 500 ms
I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-alRbk_zP0) tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your return values backward in your comparison function. From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (in a comment in the code sample):

> return true if passing nextProps to render would return
> the same result as passing prevProps to render,
> otherwise return false

You're doing the opposite, returning `false` when the minutes are the same.

Also, you're missing out the `timeObj` part (thanks Felix!), it should be `prevProps.timeObj.mins` (and the same for `newProps`). (Also, "props" should be plural, and generally best to write `.mins` rather than `['mins']`.)

Instead:

```
const Disp = React.memo(
    ({ timeObj }) => { //this Component is supposed to be in another file
        return (<Text>{timeObj.mins}</Text>);
    },
    (prevProps, newProps) => {
        // Return true if the props are the same for rendering purposes,
        // false if they aren't
        return prevProps.timeObj.mins == newProps.timeObj.mins;
    }
);
```

---

As a side note, you can use nested destructuring if all you want is the `mins` from `timeObj` (you can do that both in the component and the comparison function, but I'd probably only do it in the component, gets confusing doing the renaming needed):

```
const Disp = React.memo(
    ({ timeObj: { mins } }) => { //this Component is supposed to be in another file
        return (<Text>{mins}</Text>);
    },
    (prevProps, newProps) => {
        // Return true if the props are the same for rendering purposes,
        // false if they aren't
        return prevProps.timeObj.mins == newProps.timeObj.mins;
    }
);
```

Comment: Also `prevPop['mins']` should be `prevProp.timeObj.mins`. Same for `newProp`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling! Tunnel vision on the return value. :-D

Comment: @FelixKling oof sorry I missed that, I had it right in my actual code forgot to add it in the question :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much, I was kind of confused is to the true and false part because I thought it was `shouldRerender` as the second argument